# python how to pass multiple parameters to class without making them required

Tags: python

Ok so I am very new to python, I am taking a free class on it at a community center in SF, so yes this is "homework" but its not for school so please be explicit.

Ok so we are on operator overloading but I have a question related to parameters in a class that has me stumped. I am probably completely off track with my thinking so any assistance would be great.

Here is my code for the class so far

```
class CoinPurse(object):

    def __init__(self, quarters=0, dimes=0, nickels=0, pennies=0):
        self.purse ={'quarters': 0, 'dimes': 0, 'nickels': 0, 'pennies': 0}

    def __setitem__(self, quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies):
        self.purse ={'quarters': quarters, 'dimes': dimes, 'nickels': nickels, 'pennies': pennies}

    def amount(self):
        """ Return the amount of money as a floating point value """
        self.purseamount = 0
        self.purseamount = self.purseamount + ((self.purse['quarters']) * 25)
        self.purseamount = self.purseamount + ((self.purse['dimes']) * 10)
        self.purseamount = self.purseamount + ((self.purse['nickels']) * 5)
        self.purseamount = self.purseamount + self.purse['pennies']
        self.purseamount = float(self.purseamount) / 100

        return float(self.purseamount)

    def quarters(self):
        """ Returns the number of quarters as an integer """

        return int(self.purse['quarters'])

    def dimes(self):
        """ Returns the number of quarters as an integer """

        return int(self.purse['dimes'])

    def nickels(self):
         """ Returns the number of quarters as an integer """

        return int(self.purse['nickels'])

    def pennies(self):
        """ Returns the number of quarters as an integer """

        return int(self.purse['pennies'])
```

ok and here is a test for using the class, later I have to do a lot more with it but for right now I just want to make sure the basics are working

```
x = CoinPurse(quarters=5, pennies=100)
print x.amount()
print x.quarters()
print x.pennies()
```

now my question is this, I know I am not using **setitem** correctly how would I pass the parameters (quarters=5, pennies=100) so that they can be added to the dictionary object. I need to be passing both the key and the value (quarters is the key and 5 is the value)... I am lost on this and cant continue until I figure it out.

btw I cannot change x = CoinPurse(quarters=5, pennies=100) that has to be used that way.

**Edited code based on suggestions

```
class CoinPurse(object):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.pquarters = kwargs.get('quarters', 0)
        self.pdimes = kwargs.get('dimes', 0)
        self.pnickels = kwargs.get('nickels', 0)
        self.ppennies = kwargs.get('pennies', 0)


    def amount(self):
        """ Return the amount of money as a floating point value """
        self.purseamount = 0
        self.purseamount = self.purseamount + (self.pquarters * 25)
        self.purseamount = self.purseamount + (self.pdimes * 10)
        self.purseamount = self.purseamount + (self.pnickels * 5)
        self.purseamount = self.purseamount + self.ppennies
        self.purseamount = float(self.purseamount) / 100

        return float(self.purseamount)

    def quarters(self):
        """ Returns the number of quarters as an integer """

        return int(self.pquarters)

    def dimes(self):
        """ Returns the number of quarters as an integer """

        return int(self.pdimes)

    def nickels(self):
        """ Returns the number of quarters as an integer """

        return int(self.pnickels)

    def pennies(self):
        """ Returns the number of quarters as an integer """

        return int(self.ppennies)
```

Comment: tbh this might be better at codereview.stackexchange.com because there's lots of parts of your code that could be improved.  and you wouldn't really use setitem for this (as far as i can see).

Answer (score 1):

It would be simpler if you just made the arguments all keywords. Then you can set the individual coin quantities to a default, if they aren't given:

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    quarters = kwargs.get('quarters', 0)
    # etc. for other coins
```

You should probably also verify that no keywords other than the allowable coins are given.

Comment: That did the trick!! I hadn't seen the kwargs before, that was exactly what I was looking for. For those that come along later here is my class code now.

Comment: actually I will have to put it in the original post, check up top for the modified code.